# php json file, extract the following results from specific key

Tags: php, arrays, json

i have a list on json file, example

```
[
{"code_id":"MjI0MDA4MjEz","id_privato":"test1"}
{"code_id":"MjI0MDA4MjEz","id_privato":"test2"}
{"code_id":"MjI0MDA4MjEz","id_privato":"test3"}
{"code_id":"MjI0MDA4MjEz","id_privato":"test4"}
{"code_id":"MjI0MDA4MjEz","id_privato":"test5"}
{"code_id":"MjI0MDA4MjEz","id_privato":"test6"}
{"code_id":"MjI0MDA4MjEz","id_privato":"test7"}
]
```

I would like to extract starting from the id private_id test4, to be able to extract;

```
{"code_id":"MjI0MDA4MjEz","id_privato":"test1"}
{"code_id":"MjI0MDA4MjEz","id_privato":"test2"}
{"code_id":"MjI0MDA4MjEz","id_privato":"test3"}
```

it's possible?

use;

```
$json_gm = file_get_contents('applications/message-private/messaggi/lista_messaggi/MTQ3NzE3NDc1.json');
$json_mp_gm = json_decode($json_gm, true);
$results_list_g_m = array_filter($json_mp_gm, function($v, $k) use ($id_privato,$id_messaggio) {
    return $v['code_id'] == $id_privato && $v['id_privato'] == $id_messaggio;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

but i don't know how to start from a certain id, like the example above

Comment: ``for($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) { $results_list_g_m[]= $json_mp_gm[$i]; }``

Comment: `starting from the id private_id test4, to be able to extract...`...but then you listed things which came _before_ it, not after it. So your expected result seems to be the opposite of what you're asking for in the text.